# Design PDF template and populate data at runtime using java,xml etc

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation

well i have been looking for a java based PDF solutions...we dont have a clean way i guess-still.. all solutions are primitive and kind of workarounds... No easy solution for this requirement -
1. Designing a PDF template  using a IDE (eg. Livecycle designer ..which is not free) 
2. Then at runtime using java, populate data into this PDF template...either using xml or other datasources...

such a simple requirement and NONE has a good "open-source and free" solution yet ! Is anyone aware of any ? I have been searching for since 3-4 years now..for a clean way out...

Eclipse BIRT comes close.. but does not handle Barcode elements ..OOB.
Jasper - ireport is also good but that tool does not have a table concept and is kind of annoying !  Also barcode support is not good.

XSL-FO  has not free IDE for design .

Looking for a better answer .. got one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are your key requirements?  Does your input have to be a PDF?  If so, you'll be probably working uphill for a long time still.  Obviously you want to inject data and output a PDF.

If your templates can be something other than PDF, you could try using the OpenOffice API to get OpenOffice to do manipulate documents and produce a PDF.  [JODReports](http://jodreports.sourceforge.net) or [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) would be better ways of interacting with OpenOffice and Docmosis allows you to treat documents (doc and odt) as templates.

Comment: Thanks Jowierun.. Docmosis seems to be somewhere close there for my requirements.  Its not a 'absolute must' to have the template in PDF.. but would have been the best option - Since Business users (or their designate) could actually design the template in a PDF tool like Adobe Livecycle designer and then handover to the IT folks to use (populate data at runtime using customer data based on criteria).

Answer (score 3):

If it's a "simple requirement", you could create a report designer around iText and release it as FOSS yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a PDF file with AcroField through iText API AcroField values can be populated.
Note: Using OpenOffice you can create PDF document with FormFields.

> http://blog.rubypdf.com/2007/08/01/freely-fill-pdf-form-with-the-help-of-itext-or-itextsharp/

Answer (score 0):

You could use OpenOffice's [UNO API](http://udk.openoffice.org/).  It looks rather heavyweight but at least you get something full-featured.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [XDocReport](https://github.com/opensagres/xdocreport). You create your templates in word `.docx` or OpenOffice `.odt` files, then turn them into populated PDF files with Java code.